# Preventing some elements in a class to inherit style from it's parent class

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have HTML that looks like this

```
<div class="abc">
   <a>some link</a>
   <a class="xyz">another link</a>
</div>
```

and CSS that looks like this

```
.abc a
{
   color: #fff;
}
a.xyz
{
   color: #aaa;
}
```

The problem is second link with class xyz inherits the color #fff from it's parent div. Is there a way to make it inherit the color from class xyz? Also the concept of :first child and or :last child wont help because I just stated 2 links here which is not practical.

Comment: Can you post a working example? Because this should actually work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ssv1yyxb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably need to do is to make your CSS more specific. Without all of your code it's hard to say how specific you need to get.

```css
.abc a
{
   color: #fff;
}
.abc a.xyz
{
   color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
   <a>some link</a>
   <a class="xyz">another link</a>
</div>
```

**Reference:** [CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)